# Should the niyyah for salah be specific?

Tags: salat, practical-islam

Edit: I already know that niyyah should not be uttered but should be made within the heart. My question is something else.

Should the niyyah for the salah be specific? For example people make up certain niyyah for the fard salah like "I am going to pray 4 rakat's of Asr, behind the imam, facing the Qibla..." and what not. Can the niyyah be just that "I am praying Asr salah"? I know that niyyah shouldn't be uttered and if I even leave the house to goto the masjid for praying Asr, that's my niyyah. Also, what about salah other than fard? Salah of Friday, eid, taraweeh etc. What should be the niyyah for these prayers. Thanks.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I'm sorry but it's clearly not.

Comment: Of course it is as it explains how you make niyyah in general.

Comment: Okay I'm sorry for being ignorant. I made that comment without reading the answer that you provided. Jazakallah khair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as Niyyah is concerned, You should be specific in your **Niyyah** of **Fardh Prayers** only about the time you are praying for and the number of Rak'ats is neither necessary to be uttered nor specified.

**For Example:** It is enough for the Niyyah to be as "I am Performing Asr Salah."

While Prayers other than Fardh (Sunnah & Nafl etc) are not necessary to be specified during Niyyah.