# Niyat for jummah fard Arabic intention

Tags: salat, practical-islam, jumuah

Can someone tell me the niyat in Arabic for jummah? Like fajr fard is nayatun ossalaliyah lilala he... etc

I know it’s supposed to be said in the heart but us bengalis verbalize it in Arabic

Comment: What is the purpose to use Arabic words if the sentences are grammatically incorrect and don't mean what you intend to say! Your transliterated text means in Arabic: Intention(???) I'll pray for Allah. It would be much better if you verbalized it in your mother tongue as then you may say what you mean!

Answer (score 1):

First if you intend to pray you must do it at the moment you start your prayer as else this isn't an intention (nyyah النية) as defined by some scholars, but could be regarded as a qasd القصد (an intention to do something in future) or 'azm العزم (a determined intention to do something in future). This means in our example you should make this intention in the moment you raise your hands for the takbir at the start of the prayer. Some scholars accept any of these as an intention as long as it was done shortly before the act of worship.

Be aware that some madhhabs allow changing the niyyah within the prayer for example if you intended to pray and had in mind the wrong prayer.

If you want to verbalize an intention in Arabic you should start it with the words:

> نويت أن أصلي صلاة

translation:

> I intend to pray the prayer of …

transliteration:

> Nawaytu an osalliya salata …

instead fo the verb to pray you may also use the verb to perform in Arabic this would look like:

> نويت أداء صلاة
> transliteration:  Nawaytu adaa'a salati …

Note that usually to perform (أداء) in Arabic is used as a synonym of "to pray on time" and the opposite to "to pray a missed prayer (قضاء)".

This applies for any prayer in the example of jumuah you only add the name of the prayer and say:

> نويت أن أصلي صلاة الجمعة

or

> نويت أداء صلاة الجمعة

Some madhhabs insist on a couple of information in the niyyah like the amount of raka'as:

> ركعتين
> translation: two rak'as
> transliteration: rak'atayn

or

> ثلاث ركعات
> translation: three rak'as
> transliteration: thalath raka'aat

or

> أربع ركعات
> translation: four rak'as
> transliteration: arba'a rka'aat

Some add the intention to pray with or in congregation

> مع (هذه) الجماعة
> translation: with (this) congregation
> transliteration: ma'a (hadhihi) al-Jama'aah

or:

> جماعةً
> translation: in congregation
> transliteration: Jama'atan

Some add the intention to pray following the imam or pray with him:

> مع هذاالإمام
> transliteration: ma'a hadha al-Imam

Some insist to add that we pray for Allah so they add Lillah لله and say:

> نويت أن أصلي لله صلاة …

Be aware that the matter of niyyah as you may already realize from the different possible additions can be made more and more complicated while it is very simple: the intention is made in the heart by having in mind to perform an act of worship and verbalizing it might be helpful, but could create complications. While the majority of scholars regard it as important to have the prayer in mind one wants to actually pray some scholars like sheikh ibn 'Othaymeen say if one intends to pray the actual prayer (without giving it a name in ones mind) it is sufficient.

See also:
[Can niyat (intention) be done by heart, or must it be declared verbally?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40279/can-niyat-intention-be-done-by-heart-or-must-it-be-declared-verbally)
[Should the niyyah for salah be specific?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40702/should-the-niyyah-for-salah-be-specific?noredirect=1&lq=1)